# Problem with Number Interpolation and Plotting Code

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with a rather advanced program we were given for class.

It's supposed to; 
- read in a csv file
- arrange its elements into angles/radius arrays (and interpolate them)
- convert the arrays from polar to cartesian coordinates
- display a graph of the x, y curve and the angles/radius

I've got it so far to do most of these things, though interpolation was challenging.
However it's now giving me a specific error;

*Arrays are not almost equal to 7 decimals
first column incorrect
Mismatched elements: 363 / 364 (99.7%)
Max absolute difference: 1.97330743*

I'm pretty sure the error is stemming from this block of code;

```
angles = []
    radius = []
    angles_1 = []
    radius_1 = []
    old_radius = []
    old_angles = []
    count_angles = 1
    count_radius = 1
    with open(file_path, 'r') as filein:
        reader = csv.reader(filein, delimiter="\t")
        print(type(reader))

        for line in reader:
            #if 0 > np.array(angles) <= 360:
            old_angles.append(float(line[0]))

            #if -1.0 >= np.array(radius) <= 1.0:
            old_radius.append(float(line[1]))

        #this adds everything to the
        #convert them to numpys
            if -1.0 <= float(line[1]) <= 1.0:
                radius.append(float(line[1]))
                radius_1.append(count_radius)
            count_radius += 1

            if 0.0 <= float(line[0]) <= 360.5:
                angles.append((float(line[0])))
                angles_1.append(count_angles)
            count_angles += 1


        nu_angles = []
        for i in range(1, len(old_angles) + 1):
            nu_angles.append(np.interp(i, angles_1, angles))

        nu_radius = []
        for i in range(1, len(old_radius) + 1):
            nu_radius.append(np.interp(i, radius_1, radius))

    array_radius = np.array(nu_radius)
    array_angles = np.array(nu_angles)

    # interpolation would be
    # array[i] = array[m] + (array[n]-array[m])* (i - m)/(n-m)

    m = i - 1
    n = i + 2
    for i in array_radius:
        if -1.0 > i > 1.0:
            array_radius[i] = array_radius[m] + (array_radius[n]-array_radius[m]) * (i - m)/(n-m)

    for i in array_angles:
        if 0.0 > float(line[0]) > 360.5:
            array_angles[i] = array_angles[m] + (array_angles[n]-array_angles[m]) * (i - m)/(n-m)



    # array_radius = np.array(angles)
    # array_angles = np.array(angles)

    print(array_radius)
    print(array_angles)

    return array_angles, array_radius
```

If anyone is able to help I would greatly appreciate it.